# Input that adds a element by entering certain text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a input that adds a element by entering certain text in the input. For example If I enter RANDONTEXT in input and click submit, it should add a video element.

**HTML**

```
            <form>
                <input type="text">
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
```

**Element after entering "RANDONTEXT" in input**

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">

</video>
```

WHat should I do for javascript?

Comment: When click submit, where would you like add video element?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a working example of your request. Comments are within the code.

Note: There are a few ways to do this, I am showing you a simple example.

```js
//declare video element as a variable
const videoElement = '<video width="320" height="240" controls>' +
  '<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">' +
  '<source src="movie.ogg" type="movie.ogg">' +
'</video>'

//declare input as variable by its id
const textInput = document.getElementById("text");

//declare video element as variable by its id
const videoContainer = document.getElementById("videoContainer");

//create function that checks if "RANDONTEXT" is entered as a value in input
//if value is "RANDONTEXT" then fill the div container with the videoElement
function generateVideoFromInput() {
if (textInput.value === "RANDONTEXT") {
videoContainer.innerHTML = videoElement;
}
else {
videoContainer.innerHTML = "you didn''t enter 'RANDONTEXT' before submitting"
}
}
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text">
                <!-- call the generateVideoFromInput function when submit button is clicked -->
                <input onclick="generateVideoFromInput();" type="submit">

            
            <br />
            <br />
            
            <div id="videoContainer">video will go here after you enter "RANDONTEXT" in input and press submit.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach this with the onClick event of button:

```
var videoelem = document.createElement("video");
videoelem.setAttribute('width',320);
videoelem.setAttribute('height',240);
videoelem.setAttribute('controls',true);
var src = document.createElement("source");
src.setAttribute('src','movie.mp4');
src.setAttribute('type','video/mp4');
var src2 = document.createElement("source");
src2.setAttribute('src','movie.ogg');
src2.setAttribute('type','video/ogg');
videoelem.appendChild(src);
videoelem.appendChild(src2);
document.appendChild(videoelem);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should make the video element hidden, then unhide them using javascript if the text input is equal to RANDONTEXT

add an `id` to the text input and video

```html
<input id="thing" type="text">
<video id="video-thing" width="320" height="240" controls>
```

then using javascript, get the input value using

```js
var a = document.getElementById("thing").value
```

check if it is equal to RANDONTEXT and when it is, unhide the video elements

```js
if (a=="RANDONTEXT"){
    document.getElementById("video-thing").style.display = "block";
}
```

you can put the above code inside a function which is called when you submit the text

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add video under submit button inside form then try this.

```
    <form>
      <input id="input" type="text">
      <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="foo();">
      <div id="video"></div>
    </form>
    
    
    <script>
      function foo() {
        var name = document.getElementById("input").value;
        if(name=="RANDONTEXT")
          document.getElementById("video").innerHTML = '<video width="320" height="240" controls> <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg"></video>';
      }
    </script>
```